# get external sdcard specific folder path for all android devices

Tags: android, android-sdcard, sd-card

Is there any common way to find the specific folder in micro SD card  path  all crevices?
how to get this path by something like 
   **/storage/extSdCard/MYFOLDER**

This is my code its only working on  android 4.4.

```
String  securepath = secStoreSystem.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
String  defaul_directory_tpath = secStore+"/MYFOLDER";

secStoreSystem.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE")
```

getting null value in android 4.4+ devices

Answer (score 1):

try this

path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

String fileName = "myFile.txt";

//getting your file/folder

**File f = new File(path + File.separator + fileName);**

Comment: String path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(); File file = new File(path1 + File.separator + "MYFOLDER"); when i check file. exists() return false

Answer (score 0):

As per your code you are saving external storage path to string variable **path**
but your are using **path1** for getting your folder. Please check this.